# Android SAXParser Leftovers

Tags: android, saxparser, duplication

I have an Android app that parses XML using SAXParser. Everything goes ok, excepting some texts that get duplicated and trimmed. For example: "Just do it, even if you do not know how!" becomes " not know how!"

This is the DefaultHandler code. 10x!

```
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler()
    {
        Praise praise;
        String elementValue = null;
        Boolean elementOn = false;

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
        {

            if (localName.equals("praise"))
            {
                praise = new Praise();
                elementOn = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
        {

            // elementOn = false;

            if (localName.equals("PRAISE_TEXT"))
            {
                praise.setPraiseText(elementValue);
            }
            if (localName.equals("MOOD"))
            {
                praise.setMood(elementValue);
            }
            if (localName.equals("RATING"))
            {
                praise.setRating(Integer.valueOf(elementValue));
            }
            if (localName.equals("praise"))
            {
                elementOn = false;
                if (update)
                {
                    if (database.getPraiseByText(praise.getPraiseText(), db) == null)
                    {
                        database.addPraise(db, praise.getPraiseText(), praise.getMood(),
                            Integer.valueOf(praise.getRating()));
                    }
                }
                else
                    database.addPraise(db, praise.getPraiseText(), praise.getMood(),
                        Integer.valueOf(praise.getRating()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
        {
            // StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            if (elementOn)
            {
                elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);}}};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SaxParsing, you do not have guarantee that `characters` will be called only once!

For this, you should concatenate all the characters you receive withing the same element

This is a just your code with a small modification. You should use `StringBuilder` instead of using String (:

```
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler()
    {
        Praise praise;
        String elementValue = null;
        Boolean elementOn = false;

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
        {
            elementValue = new String();

            if (localName.equals("praise"))
            {
                praise = new Praise();
                elementOn = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
        {
            if (localName.equals("PRAISE_TEXT"))
            {
                praise.setPraiseText(elementValue);
            }
            if (localName.equals("MOOD"))
            {
                praise.setMood(elementValue);
            }
            if (localName.equals("RATING"))
            {
                praise.setRating(Integer.valueOf(elementValue));
            }
            if (localName.equals("praise"))
            {
                elementOn = false;
                if (update)
                {
                    if (database.getPraiseByText(praise.getPraiseText(), db) == null)
                    {
                        database.addPraise(db, praise.getPraiseText(), praise.getMood(),
                            Integer.valueOf(praise.getRating()));
                    }
                }
                else
                    database.addPraise(db, praise.getPraiseText(), praise.getMood(),
                        Integer.valueOf(praise.getRating()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException
        {
            // StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            if (elementOn)
            {
                elementValue = elementValue + new String(ch, start, length);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem often comes in SaxParsing. The Actual problem is it breaks the String by "/n" & only last part of String is available for us.
Now come to the solution, Take different booleans for tags(containing problems or for all).

In startElement method make relevent boolean true.

```
if (localName.equals("PRAISE_TEXT"))
{
  isPrase= true'
  praise.setPraiseText(elementValue);
}
```

in endElemet method make relevent boolean false.

```
if (localName.equals("PRAISE_TEXT"))
{
  isPrase= false;
  praise.setPraiseText(elementValue);
}
```

in characters method check for boolean like this:

```
if(isPrase)
{
 elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);}}};

}
```